# File upload php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file onto the server using php but I need some help.

I have a html form to submit a book name and a book image. The book name will be stored in the database (see below) and the image will be stored on the server.

The id, book name, and date are being stored in the database however the image is not uploading. Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks.

Database table "books"

```
id int(11), book_name varchar(255), date_added date
```

add_book.php

```
<?php

$book_name = $_POST['book'];

// insert fields to database
$sql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO books (book_name, date_added) VALUES ('$book_name', now()");  


// get id for that row
$id = mysql_insert_id();

// rename the book to that id followed by the format .jpg

$new_book_name = "$id.jpg";

// define upload path
$upload_path = "../book_images/";

// move the uploaded file to the upload path with the new name
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $upload_path . $new_book_name);

?>

<form action="add_book.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="bookform"     id="bookform">

Book name: <input name="book" type="text" id="book" value=""/> <br />
Book image: <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" />

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add book" />
</form>
```

Comment: Lot's of things can go wrong with uploading.  Instead of blindly trying to copy the file, check $_FILES['upload']['error'] first.

Answer (score 0):

Before any PHP developer begins to debug anything I always suggest in every question that do set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the very top of your script. This will tell you what went wrong on what line with respect to what statement/variable/constant

Anyways, you should check for validities whether the file uploads or not, its type and other such parameters. You should also store it by adding relative path with respect to your current working directory

```
 if(isset($_FILES["upload"])&&$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
 { 
   $name=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];

   $tempName=$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];

   $size=$_FILES["upload"]["size"];

   $type=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];

   $realPath="bookName/Imagename/".$name;

   if(($type=="image/jpg"||$type=="image/jpeg"||$type=="image/png"))
   {   
      if(is_dir($fullDirectory))  //if directory exists, then simply move it
       {
        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $realPath);   
       }
       else  //if directory doesn't exist then make one and then move the file
       {
        mkdir($fullDirectory,0777,true);

        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $realPath);

       }
    }
    else
    {
     print $_FILES["upload"]["error"];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spme thing is wrong here:

```
 $new_book_name = "$id.jpg";
```

You should take file name from POST here `$_FILES["upload"]["name"]`. and add $id with this file name:

```
$new_book_name = $id."-".$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
```

Also check permission in your upload directory "../book_images/".